# Request Permissions exceptions in app

Tags: android

What does these exceptions really mean?I have already given the permission of Internet in manifest file.

```
05-02 15:21:31.019 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
    05-02 15:21:31.019 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 193: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
    05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 160: Landroid/app/Activity;.onRequestPermissionsResult (I[Ljava/lang/String;[I)V
    05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
    05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
    05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
    05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 227: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

LOGCAT after running the app-

```
05-02 15:21:31.019 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:21:31.019 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 193: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 160: Landroid/app/Activity;.onRequestPermissionsResult (I[Ljava/lang/String;[I)V
05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:21:31.031 6603-6603/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 227: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
05-02 15:53:47.830 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.Login.access$super
05-02 15:53:47.830 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 193: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
05-02 15:53:47.834 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.Login.access$super
05-02 15:53:47.834 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 160: Landroid/app/Activity;.onRequestPermissionsResult (I[Ljava/lang/String;[I)V
05-02 15:53:47.834 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.Login.access$super
05-02 15:53:47.834 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
05-02 15:53:47.834 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.Login.access$super
05-02 15:53:47.834 16081-16081/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 227: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
05-02 15:54:04.238 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:54:04.238 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 193: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
05-02 15:54:04.246 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:54:04.246 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 160: Landroid/app/Activity;.onRequestPermissionsResult (I[Ljava/lang/String;[I)V
05-02 15:54:04.246 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:54:04.246 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
05-02 15:54:04.246 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method com.example.somya.client_feedback_application.MainActivity.access$super
05-02 15:54:04.246 16517-16517/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 227: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are not exceptions. They are messages from the runtime, indicating that your code refers to classes or methods that do not appear to exist on the version of Android you are running on. This is typical if you are using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to conditionally execute code on newer devices and skip that code on older devices.

Comment: Thanks.My current target targetSdkVersion is 23.I will downgrade it to 22.Then will retry to run the code.

Comment: @SomyaArora: Your `targetSdkVersion` has nothing to do with these messages.

Comment: @SomyaArora: Since there is no problem, there is nothing that needs to be solved. There are ~1.5 billion Android devices in use. Most of them will log these messages for most Android apps that are in use. These messages are perfectly normal. Generally, you just ignore them.

Comment: But my app is crashing.I have attached above the logcat after running the app.Please check that out.

Comment: @SomyaArora: "But my app is crashing" -- how have you determined this? "I have attached above the logcat after running the app" -- there is no [Java stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) there, and so that is not a sign that your app is crashing.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thank you, first time I've seen these runtime logging messages - your answer confirmed what I thought already.